# Is it ok to front suspended tow a 2017 Dacia Duster 1.5dci 4wd?

Tags: towing, 4wd

I have a 2017 Duster 4x4 and want to tow it behind my motorhome on a trailer dolly which holds the front wheels. The rear wheels will still turn so I was concerned this may damage the 4 wheel drive system.

Comment: It's probably NOT ok to tow this vehicle with wheels on the ground without removing the front-to-rear driveshaft.  But as noted, the Owner's Manual should provide towing information.

Comment: Are you stuck with the Duster?  You might be better to sell it and buy a front-wheel drive vehicle, which is much more likely to work with your doilly.

Comment: @Criggie I wouldn't sell the Duster but rather the dolly and get a full-size vehicle trailer. Probably more bang for buck.

Comment: Thanks for that

Answer (score 10):

I found this in the [owners manual](https://gimmemanuals.com/owners/2021/08/2014-dacia-duster-owners-manual.pdf) for the vehicle, which says that it must not be towed with any wheels on the ground -

[image]

Comment: When towing 4WD vehicles with one axle on the ground (further than "out of the ditch"), it's necessary to disconnect the driveshaft (as [jwh20 noted](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/91171/is-it-ok-to-front-suspended-tow-a-2017-dacia-duster-1-5dci-4wd#comment156729_91171). That's usually not done in a breakdown recovery, and probably isn't practical for doing behind an RV where the dingy is expected to be used daily. It could be practical for a long journey where it won't be used for days/weeks.

Comment: Excellent thanks